# For a Set of Integers, Get All Sets Whose Sum is Greater Than Some Value

Tags: set, permutation, subset-sum

Let me start by saying I have found many questions and answers that answer things which seem somewhat related or close to this question, but are not actually this question. It seems related to the coin change / subset sum problem, but I think this is distinctly different enough that subset sum answers do not cover this question.

**The Problem**

Let's say I have a set of 4 integers called **S** : `[1, 2, 5, 1]`

The goal is to devise a set of sets, **G** , that is comprised of each subset of **S** where the sum of the set is greater than some value **N**.

In this example, if **N = 6**, then **G** would be `[ [5,2,1,1], [5,2,1], [5,2], [5,1,1] ]`

**Considerations**

I chose the word set here specifically because the order of each set does not matter at all.  `[5, 2, 1, 1]` is identical to `[5, 1, 1, 2]`.

When you create your first set that exceeds **N**, lets say **G<sub>1</sub>**, you can also immediately add all other sets which contain **G<sub>1</sub>** as a subset. Likewise, if you find another new set **G<sub>2</sub>** that has not already added and also exceeds **N**, you can immediately add all sets which contain **G<sub>2</sub>** as a subset. You don't need to check if these sets sum to greater than **N**.

If you sum all the members of **S** and the result is not greater than **N**, then you can conclude there are no sets which meet the criteria.

**Actual Use-case**

The real-world goal that is trying to be met here is that I have a group of items which have a numerical weight associated with them, and another value which represents a threshold. I'm trying find out if its even feasible to routinely find all the sub-groups that can be made of the items that exceed the threshold when their weights are summed.

**What is the most efficient way to generate all sets that meet this criteria? What is complexity of this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a more efficient implementation. Worthwhile notes:

- It correctly handles duplicate elements to avoid returning the same subset twice
- In fact, it avoids recomputing equivalent subsets altogether, by grouping same-valued elements into bins with counts
- It starts from the largest subset (the set itself) and gradually removes elements while staying above the threshold, and early-exits to avoid exploring smaller subsets entirely
- It uses list mutation to avoid expensive list creation / coping until absolutely necessary
- It does use recursion, so there's a small performance penalty there, and as with all recursion: if you throw a large enough input at it, it will raise an error. Its an exercise to the reader to port this to an iterative variant if that becomes an issue

```py
from collections import Counter

def solve(nums, target):
    counts = sorted(Counter(nums).items())
    reserve = sum(nums) - target
    
    if reserve <= 0:
        return []
    return list(_solve(counts, reserve, []))

def _solve(counts, reserve, prefix):
    if not counts:
        yield tuple(prefix)
        return
    
    val, max_count = last = counts.pop()
    
    prefix.extend([val] * max_count)
    yield from _solve(counts, reserve, prefix)
    
    for count in range(1, max_count + 1):
        prefix.pop()
        if reserve - count * val > 0:
            yield from _solve(counts, reserve - count * val, prefix)
    
    counts.append(last)
```

Timing it:

```py
from timeit import timeit

runs = 10
statement = "solve([randrange(15) for _ in range(25)], 100)"
setup = "from __main__ import solve; from random import randrange"
print(timeit(statement, setup=setup, number=runs)/runs)
```

Output:

```
0.22455865999218078
```

Meaning its able to solve problems of 25 elements where the solution contains ~100k distinct subsets in about 225ms.

I did test this against a naive solution to ensure correctness as well.

Regarding time complexity, its hard to bound this, because its run time really depends on the value of the numbers (or rather, the output size).  You could bound it as `O(n log n + s * n)` where `n` is the size of the input list, and `s` is the size of the output list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools` to generate sub-lists and then filter those lists based on a condition:

```
import itertools

input_list = [1, 2, 5, 1]
threshold = 6

result = []

for length in range(len(input_list) + 1):

    search_space = list(itertools.combinations(input_list, length))

    for item in search_space:
        if sum(item) > threshold:
            result.append(item)

print(result)
```

Time complexity is quite high as you first need to generate sub-lists of every length (outer for loop), then search right values based on condition (inner for loop), so it will be at least O(n^2).

Comment: The time complexity on this is massively under-estimated. You explore every subset of the initial set (its "power set"), meaning `2^N` subsets. For each, you iterate over the set in `sum()`, so its `O(n * 2^n)`, for `n` numbers in the list

Comment: Also, the result is arguably wrong. The OP asks for distinct sets (indicated by the example), but this code returns duplicate sets with different orderings.